# Composite component jsf * primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, composite-component

i have problem to use widgetVar while its name is generated dynamicly. How properly we can call such widget ? Code of component:

```
<cc:attribute name="id" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
...
<cc:implementation>
    <p:selectOneRadio widgetVar="widgetVariable#{cc.attrs.id}" id="#{cc.attrs.id}" required="false" immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"
                      value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <p:ajax event="click" oncomplete="checkRadio()"/>
        <cc:insertChildren/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*  <![CDATA[ */

        function checkRadio() {
            var widgetVariable = widgetVariable#{cc.attrs.id}; //HERE PROBLEM
            widgetVariable.dosmth();
        }

        /*    ]]> */
    </script>
</cc:implementation>
```

thats what is wird that it works, but when i uses many istance of this component on page widgetwar sometimes get crazy and make javascript for many istance of component.

Edit: everything works fine.
Anyway i have one new problem. I created in this .js file some global state variable.

```
var state = -1;

function checkRadio() {
        var widgetVariable = widgetVariable#{cc.attrs.id}; //HERE PROBLEM
        widgetVariable.dosmth(state);
}
```

But each state should be only for one composite istance, atm every composite use this var, some ideas?

Comment: How does the `id` look like? What characters does it contain?

Comment: any, some letters/numbers "myCompoennt" "something2" etc.

Comment: So no special characters, just alphanumeric characters?

Comment: yup, i am testing atm Balus soltuions, brb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 2 problems.

The first problem is that you're declaring JS functions in a XHTML file instead of a real JS file. If you've multiple of those components, then you're basically generating multiple JS functions `checkRadio()` to the HTML output. Pull the page in your browser, rightclick and *View Source*. You'll basically see

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkRadio() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkRadio() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkRadio() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
...
```

They're overriding each other until the last one. So when `checkRadio()` is called, *actually* the last one will be invoked. This obviously isn't right.

You should have only one function. You can externalize the variable by simply making it a function argument. Even more, you should not be writing JS code in a XHTML file, but in a standalone JS file which you include by `<h:outputScript>`. Additional bonus, it will automatically make sure that there's only one JS file loaded even though you've multiple composite components.

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputScript name="myComposite.js" />
    ...
    <p:ajax event="click" oncomplete="checkRadio('#{cc.attrs.id}')" />
</cc:implementation>
```

Coming back to your concrete question, your second problem, you can make use of `window[variableName]` notation to get a hand of a global (window) variable by a dynamically composed variable name. So, the `checkRadio()` function in your `myComposite.js` (name it whatever you want, but the same filename as `myComposite.xhtml` would be most self-documenting) should look like this:

```
function checkRadio(compositeId) {
   var widgetVariableName = "widgetVariable" + compositeId;
   var widgetVariable = window[widgetVariableName];
   widgetVariable.dosmth();
}
```

Comment: where should i put this js file? i added libary tag 
<h:outputScript library="js" name="compositeJS.js" /> I puted it into place where composite component is, but it show me some erorr in page source when i am going to page with this composite component:
... <td class="value"><script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script> ...

Comment: The same place as all other JSF resources. In the `/resources` folder. If you want it to be in the same folder as composite XHTML, just alter `<h:outputScript library>` accordingly based on the actual `/resources`-relative path. By the way, "js" is absolutely a bad library name. See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: Just pass it as another function argument?

Comment: each Composite component can have many states, and i need to remember this states.
for example i got
1th state = 3
2nd state = 2
3rd state = 0
atm this var state is global and all of them uses it. So passing its not a solution while this var can have 1 state at once

Comment: I'm not seeing how passing it as another function argument forms a problem.

Comment: I think we talk about 2 diffrent things. I have problem to crate dynamicly variables for states of each component, cus i have only one state variable and even that var state is in own file it still included in javascript of all components at page.

Comment: ok i fixed it. I didnt knew that I even dont need to declare global JS variables so i replaced each state to:
window[stateName] where stateName = "state" + compositeId; //compositeID from function arguments